# Dplyr mutate example includes excess variable but never performs any action on it, why?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to learn more about dplyr and while looking at the [documentation examples](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) I noticed Hadley/Garrett include a variable in a mutate function but they don't actually operate on it.

```
starwars %>% 
  mutate(name, bmi = mass / ((height / 100)  ^ 2)) %>%
  select(name:mass, bmi)
```

Is there a reason the `name` variable was included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no purpose, it’s an oversight.